# Passing Mat from C to python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ctypes, mat

I need to return Mat result from C function back to Python and convert it to numpy.array. I do not know the size of the resulted Mat before I make the call so I can't pass pointer to an existing array. Here is my code:

Python:

```
def Utils_FindFeatures(image):
    comDll.FindFeatures.argtypes = [ndpointer(c_uint8, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"), c_size_t, c_size_t, c_size_t, ndpointer(c_uint8, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS")] 
    comDll.FindFeatures.restype = None
    descriptors = ???
    comDll.FindFeatures(image.astype(c_uint8), image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 0, descriptors)
```

C++

```
uchar* MatToBytes(Mat image, int& image_size)
{
    image_size = image.total() * image.elemSize();
    uchar * image_uchar = new uchar[image_size];
    //image_uchar is a class data member of uchar*
    std::memcpy(image_uchar, image.data, image_size * sizeof(uchar));
    return image_uchar;
}

Mat BytesToMat(int image_rows, int image_cols, int image_type, void* image_uchar)
{

   Mat img(image_rows, image_cols, image_type, image_uchar, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);
   return img;
}

static SurfFeaturesFinder sf;
void FindFeatures(const int* image_uchar, int image_rows, int image_cols, int image_type, int* descriptors)
{
    ImageFeatures features;
    Mat img = BytesToMat(image_rows, image_cols, image_type, (void*)image_uchar);
    sf(img, features);

    int size = 0;
    Mat matDescriptor;
    features.descriptors.copyTo(matDescriptor);
    descriptors = (int*) MatToBytes(matDescriptor, size);
}
```

Apparently "descriptors" is not updated.
I also need to return KeyPoint but I will deal with it after the first step.

Comment: You're assigning to a local copy of `descriptors`, not the thing it points to.  Also `image_uchar` is declared as a pointer to `const int`, but you're passing it a pointer to `uint8_t`.

Comment: My problem is not the input parameter but output. C++ read the matrix OK, but how can I return the result back to "descriptors". As I mention I don't know how to define the descriptors because it cannot point to an existing array because I don't know the size of the result.